# Nginx always gives "502 Bad Gateway"

Tags: nginx, httpd, mod-proxy

I am using axis2 web server. I want to access it through Nginx. Here is my nginx configs

```
server {
          listen 443;
          server_name malintha.com;
          ssl on;
          ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/wso2esbserver.crt;
          ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/wso2esbserver.key;
          location /carbon {
              proxy_pass https://10.100.1.30:9443;
          }

}
```

My server is running and I can access it directly. But nginx gives me "502 Bad Gateway" when I access that web server through nginx. What can be the root cause for this ?

**Curl result**

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.

**Error Log**

2015/01/04 19:59:19 [error] 30334#0: *3 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:100AE081:elliptic curve routines:EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name:unknown group error:1408D010:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_KEY_EXCHANGE:EC lib) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 10.174.14.28, server: malintha.com, request: "GET /carbon HTTP/1.1", upstream:

Comment: Show the error log entry, and/or the result of `curl -I https://10.100.1.30:9443/carbon` from the server running nginx. Are you really wanting to preserve the `/carbon` url prefix?

Comment: edit question with required daata

Comment: Please read and action the message curl is giving you about certificate verification, rather than blindly pasting it into the question; and use a code block **including the command** to assure readers as to what command/url it corresponds to.

Comment: You forgot to mention your Linux distribution and version!

Comment: could it be an outdated openssl package with wrong ciphers set? what is your ssl environment?

Comment: The problem does not come from nginx but from the TLS handshake with your upstream.

Is not this related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/22997056?